# Cassandra : Are clustering key ordered in wide row in ASC order by default?

Tags: cassandra, cql

Lets say we have row key like this in Cassandra

country + state + city 
Where country is partition key , state and city are clustering key .

So I insert records like this

```
India , Himachal,  Manali
India , Karnataka,  Mysore
India , Karnataka,  Bagalkot 
India , Maharashtra,  Pune 
India  , Maharashtra  , Mumbai
India  , Maharashtra  , Nagpur
India  , Maharashtra  , Kolhapur
India , Karnataka,  Bangalore 
India , Himachal,  Shimla
USA , California , San Jose 
USA , California , palo alto
```

In cassandra wide row key will be India, USA  but clustering key is state + city 
So when I read data will I get state and city in ascending order ?Like

```
India , Himachal,  Manali
India , Himachal,  Shimla
India , Karnataka,  Bagalkot 
India , Karnataka,  Bangalore 
India  , Maharashtra  , Kolhapur
India  , Maharashtra  , Mumbai
India , Maharashtra,  Pune 

USA , California , palo alto 
USA , California , San Jose
```

Is this expected read by Cassandra ? Clustering key in order ?

In short is Cassandra can be considered as data structure ?

```
Map<State sortedMap<state , sortedMap<city , value >>>
```

Comment: For usefulness of others looking at this question, could you please provide your table schema?  (i.e. 'CREATE TABLE...etc.')

Comment: See [here][1] for a more detailed explanation on clustering key ordering.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18636959/1662877

Answer (score 2):

The default clustering order is indeed ascending, via the [CREATE TABLE](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/create_table_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_v3f_vfk_xj__ordering-results) documentation:

> You can order query results to make use of the on-disk sorting of columns. You can order results in ascending or descending order. The ascending order will be more efficient than descending. If you need results in descending order, you can specify a clustering order to store columns on disk in the reverse order of the default. Descending queries will then be faster than ascending ones.

```
Map<country, sortedMap<state, sortedMap<city, value>>
```

Your Map interpretation does seem right if your primary key is (country, state, city).

Answer (score 2):

Clustering order is indeed ascending by default, but can be configured during the table creation

```
create table TABLE_NAME (
  Partionkey_event text,
  ClusterKey_time timestamp,
  ....,
  PRIMARY KEY (Partionkey_event, ClusterKey_time)
)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (ClusterKey_time DESC);
```

For ascending order you can stop specifying clustering order, which would ascending. Or you could specify as below

```
create table TABLE_NAME (
  Partionkey_event text,
  ClusterKey_time timestamp,
  ....,
  PRIMARY KEY (Partionkey_event, ClusterKey_time)
)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (ClusterKey_time ASC);
```

More information here:
http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/refClstrOrdr.html